# mediaplayer mp3 not working wpf

Tags: wpf, mp3

I have an issue with MediaPlayer class in WPF application.
My project looks like this:

[image: Project Structure]

The issue is: When my AboutDialog is initialized and appears, it doesn't play the AboutDialogSound.mp3. I think the problem is the Uri string format, I tried changing it but I still didn't work.

I'm sorry I'm not good at English. Please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least, there are two problems in your code, regarding how you attempted to play mp3 file using `MediaPlayer` :

1. The main problem as you already suspected, is the wrong path to the file. Relative path means relative to the executable file. In development phase, it is inside `bin\debug` folder. So the path to the mp3 file should be `"../../AboutDialogSound.mp3"`.
2. Another problem is declaring `MediaPlayer` object as local variable. By doing this, the object will be garbage-collected soon after the method where variable declared (`AboutDialog` constructor in this case) finished. So if you managed to fix the first problem, you  will hear audio file played for a moment, then suddenly stopped because the `MediaPlayer` playing it GC-ed. Declare it as global variable instead of local.

Tips : To check for failure in `MediaPlayer` (such as file not found because of the wrong path), try to subscribe to the `MediaFailed` event. Because `MediaPlayer` doesn't throw exception, it trigger `MediaFailed` event instead.

```
public partial class AboutDialog
{
    private MediaPlayer player;

    public AboutDialog()
    {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.MediaFailed += (o, args) =>
                                  {
                                      MessageBox.Show("Media Failed!!");
                                  };
        player.Open(new Uri("../../AboutDialogSound.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        player.Play();
    }
    .....
}
```

Reference : http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/playing-audio/

Comment: Thanks. The first problem you mentioned solved my issue. I copied my mp3 file to the /bin folder and then the window played the sound as soon as it loaded :D

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the resources (mp3 files) are “Copy always” in copy to Output Directory in properties.

```
player.Open(new Uri(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + @“\Resources\filename.mp3”)); 
player.Play();
```

Comment: Worked when I pasted my MP3 to output directory.